# IAP Fail delivering the receipt after a succes po-up

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have 2 issues :

1. After purchasing a subscription I receive the "**You are all set** Your purchase was successful" but in the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` I receive the `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` state with `"Cannot connect to iTunes Store"` error.
2. Some time when the purchase is  initiated i receive a **Confirm Purchase** pop up but also the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is called with fail state

**NOTE:** I'm testing on simulator with Network Link Conditioner ( HighLatencyDNS custom profile 500ms)

Also I have notice this issue in the networks with high DNS latency more than 0.5 sec

Add Payment to queue:

```
- (BOOL)internalBeginPurchaseFor:(NSString *)productId
{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKProduct *product;
        if ((product = self.products[productId])) {
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Processing transaction state:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        NSString *transactionIdentifier = transaction.transactionIdentifier;
        NSString *transactionDetails = @"";

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"User is purchasing");
                transactionDetails = @"User purchasing";
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: 
                NSLog(@"User purchased");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                [self executeHandlerForTransaction:transaction andSuccessFlag:YES];
                transactionDetails = @"User purchased";
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"failed to purchase");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                [self executeHandlerForTransaction:transaction andSuccessFlag:NO];
                transactionDetails = @"Failed to purchase";
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restored transaction");
                transactionDetails = @"Restored transaction";
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                NSLog(@"pending for transaction");
                transactionDetails = @"Pending for transaction";
                break;
        }

        NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ for transaction Identifier %@",transactionDetails, transactionIdentifier];
        [EventLogger logEventOfType:PURCHASE_PLAN withData:stringData andNotes:@"APIAPurchase"];

    }
}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Show your code where you process the transaction states.

Comment: @Paulw11 just added.

Comment: I recommend you to test them using a real device.

Comment: Indeed on a real device with developer settings with a high Latency option activated i still managed to accomplish the purchase.